# WCF - call a function with await key throws an exception

Tags: wcf, xamarin, async-await, uwp, navision

I get the following error:

> This IRandomAccessStream does not support the GetInputStreamAt method
>   because it requires cloning and this stream does not support cloning.

My customer runs an test azure webservice of microsoft nav server.

> SOAP is my Service Reference

### ISoapService.cs

```
public interface ISoapService
{
    Task<string> ShipGetNewBatchCode(string macAddress);
}
```

### SoapService.cs

```
public class SoapService : ISoapService
{
    private SOAP.scan_PortClient soapClient;

    public SoapService()
    {
        ConfigurateSoapService();
    }

    public async Task<string> ShipGetNewBatchCode(string macAddress)
    {
        var retValue = "";

        try
        {
            var response = await soapClient.ShipGetNewBatchCodeAsync(macAddress);
            retValue = response.return_value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return retValue;
    }

    private void ConfigurateSoapService()
    {
        var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var uri = new Uri("http://***aka.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:*2/**/**/****/**/***");
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);

        binding.Name = "scan_Binding";
        binding.CloseTimeout = timespan;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timespan;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timespan;
        binding.SendTimeout = timespan;
        //binding.AllowCookies = false;
        ///binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        //binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
        //binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        //binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;

        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;

        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        soapClient = new SOAP.scan_PortClient(binding, endpoint);
        soapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****", "*****");
    }
}
```

### ViewModel Class

```
var soapService = DependencyService.Get<ISoapService>();
var a = await soapService.ShipGetNewBatchCode("11");
```

Comment: There was a problem using network credentials. Try to not provide it. If you want to share your exact URI I can try to generate a proxy and test your service

Comment: One more thing I noticed. You are defining TransportCredentialOnly, so your URL has to be https (I think...).

Comment: @YuriS **TransportCredentialOnyl** is for HTTP. I'm defining otherwise I get error with authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
When I add a service reference to an _UWP_ project (i was not able to add a web reference). 
I tried this code on a console application and it works. But it does not want work by UWP.
Send me a mail support@sdt-informatics.be, I will send you the credentials.

Comment: Sent email. Few questions. Are you using Forms or Classic? Do you care about Phone 8.1 platform? Do you use PCL .net standard or default profile? I want to reproduce so the info how you create your project will be very helpful, alternatively you can email me the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this problem by deleting the following reference:

> Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps

and I updated

> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

to version v5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest to consider using ServiceReference in PCL to get common client. But regardless... Solution is below

```
    public async Task<string> ShipGetNewBatchCode(string macAddress)
    {
        var retValue = "";

        try
        {
            string uri = "http://youruri";
            Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter hbpf = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
            Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential pcred = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(uri, 
                "userName", "password");
            hbpf.ServerCredential = pcred;

            Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient hc = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(hbpf);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage hreqm = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(uri));
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage hrespm = await hc.SendRequestAsync(hreqm);
            if (hrespm.StatusCode == Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            {
                soapClient = new SOAP.scan_PortClient();
                var response = await soapClient.ShipGetNewBatchCodeAsync(macAddress);
                retValue = response.return_value;
            }
            else
            {
                //process error
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return retValue;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I get same error at line 39 (var response = await soapClient.ShipGetNewBatchCodeAsync(macAddress);
with which device did you try ?

Comment: I run it on my local machine